# error en codigo vb.net al llenar treeview

Tags: vb.net

El error es que el valor char no se puede converti en datatable, cual
seria la solucion

```
Dim dataViewHijos As DataView 
dataViewHijos = New DataView(dt.TableName(CInt("TablaArbol")))
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tienes un lío al asignar el valor al `DataView` pues espera un DataTable y tu le pasas otra cosa (que no se entiende, pues intentas pasar a entero un string que claramente no puede serlo).

Si el `dt` es un DataTable, debería ser

```
dataViewHijos = New DataView(dt)
```

Si el `dt` es un DataSet, debería ser

```
dataViewHijos = New DataView(dt.Tables("TablaArbol"))
```

**EDITO TRAS COMENTARIO**

El problema es que estás concatenando mal el filtro, si buscas un string debes poner comillas simples.

```
Dim filtro as string = dtTabla.Columns("IdentificadorPadre").ColumnName & " = '" & indicePadre.ToString() & "'"
dataViewHijos.RowFilter = filtro
```

Comment: si tenia razon con respecto al asignarle el valor al dataview, ahora sucede que en el sigiuente codigo                                                                                     dataViewHijos.RowFilter = dtTabla.Columns("IdentificadorPadre").ColumnName + _
        " = " + indicePadre.ToString()

Comment: No he entendido muy bien el error, pero he intentado responderte editando la respuesta